# create new start date variable that is earliest date from multiple columns

Tags: sas

I want to compare three columns and make a new variable, start, that retains the earliest date recorded. I would love something to be more efficient because this computer is struggling.

```
data new1;
set new;
format start date MMDDYY10;
if input(service_start, MMDDYY10) < input(Pay_start,MMDDYY10) and input(service_start, MMDDYY10) < input(cost_start,MMDDYY10) then start = service_start;
Else if input(Pay_start,MMDDYY10) < input(service_start, MMDDYY10) and input(Pay_start,MMDDYY10) < input(cost_start,MMDDYY10) then start = pay_start;
Else start = cost_start;
run;
```

Comment: If your computer is struggling, this isn't the reason; three if/else statements aren't going to tick much on your CPU usage.

Comment: Sounds like you may be dealing with a large table? If so, you may benefit from turning on `options compress=yes;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data new1;
    set new;
    format start date MMDDYY10.;
    start = min( input( service_start, MMDDYY10. ), input( Pay_start, MMDDYY10. ), input( cost_start, MMDDYY10. );
run;
```